# Sed putting through weird errors?

Tags: bash, sed

I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

I have a sed command being executed here (it's an M1 Mac, which I know has a different version of sed than GNU sed, which could be the problem? But i need the command to act the same on Linux/Windows/Mac:

```bash
firstString="SQLITE_KEY=\"?.*\"?[^\w\d]"
secondString="SQLITE_KEY=\"?${SQLITE_KEY_GENERATED}\"?"

sed -i '' -r "/SQLITE_KEY/ s/${firstString}/${secondString}/" .env
```

I have a set of environment variables in another file, and these are injected into the .env file:

```
SQLITE_KEY=zCokzf3aVzS0T7cH3mJiyrqUBK5YpETwqVf4tg==
```

However when I run it, I get an error like this.

```bash
sed: 1: "/SQLITE_KEY/ s/SQLITE_K ...": bad flag in substitute command: 't'
```

The goal here is to take the environment variables from the source file, and inject them into the .env file where SQLITE_KEY is. The "bad flag" warning changes letters every time, so I'm suspecting it's something to do with the formatting of the password.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message suggests there's something like a "/" in `$SQLITE_KEY_GENERATED` -- what is its value? Putting `set -x` before the command to get bash's interpretation of what the command is may help here. Also, you seem to be mixing GNU vs macOS/BSD sed syntax: `-i ''` is macOS syntax, but `-r` is GNU (`-E`  works for both versions), and in the regex, `[^\w\d]` is nonstandard and won't work with macOS' sed (I think you want `[^[:alnum:]]` or something similar).

Comment: such terrific feedback - lemme run it and find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax conflict involving double-quotes (").

secondString  has escaped '"'.

Those are then interpreted by the shell command after the variable substitution for sed.

So ... you need to replace the outside double-quotes by single-quotes on the sed, in this way:

eval sed -i \'\' -r \'/SQLITE_KEY/ s/${firstString}/${secondString}/\' .env

This way, the double-quotes will be correctly carried thru into the .env file.